# What dishes pair well the Maltese Harruba liqueur?

Tags: recommendations, liqueur

What food stuffs pair well with the Maltese liqueur Harruba?

A friend of mine has several bottles of this sweet liqueur and we are hoping to make it into a meal of something more than just the ordinary.

[image]

> The [carob tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carob), in Maltese called Harruba **(Ceratonia siliqua)** has been a prominent component of the Maltese vegetation for several centuries. The fruit beans of this tree, also known as ‘St. John’s bread’ formed a substantial part of the diet of the local population during the hard times of World War II.
>   Carob beans, harvested by Maltese farmers, are crushed, roasted and boiled to produce a syrupy liquid with aromas and colour reminiscent of cocoa to which orange extracts are then added. Zeppi’s Harruba liqueur can be served chilled, on the rocks or can also be taken neat to close off an exquisite meal. Harmless sediment may form at the bottom of the bottle due to the nature of the product. -
>   [Mediterranean Maltese Liqueur](http://safifields.blogspot.com/2012/10/mediterranean-maltese-liqueur.html)

Comment: Sounds like an after dinner aperitif. Perhaps enjoyed like Port with cheese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it is probably too sweet to be enjoyed as part of a meal except as an aperitif as @Eric suggested.

Since Carob tastes like chocolate and this is a sweet strong liqueur. Maybe consider using it in a Tiramisu recipe as a substitute for Marsala? I have used Amaretto in this way before and it was delicious!

Carob is often used as a substitute for chocolate so any liqueur based recipes where you want a hint of chocolate flavour would benefit from this. Maybe in a beef based dish (as we know a hint of dark chocolate in a beef casserole or chilli is a great trick!)

I found [this article](https://www.cookinglight.com/cooking-101/how-to-cook-with-liquors-spirits"Cookinglight.com") online which could give you some inspiration.